# Adding a foreign key constraint

Tags: sql, oracle10g, ddl

Is it possible to add a constraint just like foreign key after inserting some values in the table?

If it's possible how can I do it, because I'm trying to add it with

```
alter table ...add constraint ..foreign key .."
```

But I get an error:

> impossible de valider (SYS.COMPAGNIEID1) - clés parents introuvables.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask].  Yes, it is possible.  What database?  Don't tag with everything under the sun.  Please show messages in English.  Not everyone know French.

Comment: okey but how can i add this constraint  please

Comment: Sounds as if you have rows in your table that contain invalid values for the foreign key, that is: values that do not exist in the referenced table.

Comment: Unrelated, but: do **NOT** create tables as `SYS`. **Never**, ever do that. Just don't. Create a regular user and create your tables there. **Stop** using the `SYS` account for your normal work.

Comment: this my first project in sql for that the teacher ask as to create a sys account ,but will not do it in an other project thank you

Answer (score 0):

In order to have a define a foreign key, you have to have defined a primary key in the "parent" table. For example, using the standard EMP and DEPT tables, you would first define the column DEPTNO as a primary key in the DEPT table. You would then define DEPTNO in EMP table as a foreign key, that references DEPTNO in DEPT. If you have data in you table, (by default) the data will be validated to make sure the data conforms to the constraints.

Comment: so it's not a problem to define a new foreign key after inserting some values in the table

Comment: @hafssaaboulghit  it's not a problem in so far as it's possible. However, if you have rows that do not conform to the constraint, the statement will fail.